# Failure after upgrading project from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 => the type or namespace name 'MaxLength'/'Column' could not be found

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, data-annotations

I have a working website targeting .Net 4.0 and entity framework 4.3.1. 
After installing .Net 4.5 ( with Visual Studio Express 2012 ) I can compile the website on Visual Web Developer Express 2010 but when i try to navigate to

```
http://localhost/
```

I get this error:

CS0246 “The type or namespace name 'MaxLength' could not be found” on

```
[Column("titulo"), Required(), MaxLength(150)]
Línea 13:         public string Titulo { get; set; }
```

I have this using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

The application pool on IIS is configured for .Net 4.0.

I tried updating Entity framework to 4.4 ( from Nuget ) and added this using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

But then the error is:

CS0246 “The type or namespace name 'Column' could not be found”

Any suggestion to solve the problem?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this work you have to do the following:

1. Open NuGet package manager and find in the `Installed packages` tab
   the Entity Framework package. Uninstall it.
2. Now Go to the `Online` tab and search for Entity Framework. Hit
   install. Now your project should reference the correct version of EF
   that is `5.0` instead of `4.4.0` (the version I had before intalling
   this new version).

Hope it helps.

For more info, take a look here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1779042.aspx/1

Answer (score -1):

May be you need to add some references, which you using in your solution(right click on your project - Add Reference...)

Comment: Do not think I missed any reference. Within Visual Studio compiles correctly and prior to install .Net 4.5 worked.