# TableAttribute is ambiguous in the namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema after conversion to .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I've converted an ASP.net MVC 4 project from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 following the technique outlined in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524035/753737) -- in particular in the `vbproj` file I've set `TargetFramework` to `v4.5` and `Prefer32Bit` to `false`.

I now get the following error in the Entity Framework model (inherited from the MVC template project)

```
TableAttribute is ambiguous in the namespace
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```

Using Object Explorer I've seen that `TableAttribute` in present in assemblies `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` (taken from the reference assemblies) and `EntityFramework.dll` (taken from Entity Framework 5 installed from NuGet).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Browsing through similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024681/mvc4-api-on-azure-websites-or-azure-cloud-services-error-system-componentmo) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175389/failure-after-upgrading-project-from-net-4-0-to-net-4-5-the-type-or-namespa) I've understood that, since I've done a manual conversion, the reference of `EntityFramework.dll` was not updated to point to the (correct) .NET 4.5 assembly.

I removed and re-added the Nuget package and the project compiles -- now `TableAttribute` is present only in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`.

Comment: Man wouldn't it be nice if we didn't have to lose hours to the stupidity of the tooling. NuGet is such a POS sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using NPM (Nuget Package Manager) then issue the command:

```
update-package EntityFramework
```

Rebuild the project if the error still persist and it will be fixed. This is how I got to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and I only removed the entity framework reference from framework 4.0 folder and added again from framework 4.5 folder in packages under solution